# Rubyでのオブジェクト指向設計実践ガイド コンポーズされたBicycleでのエラー

Tags: ruby

オブジェクト指向設計実践ガイド
Rubyでわかる進化し続ける柔軟なアプリケーションでの育て方を参考に学習しております。

第８章 コンポジションでオブジェクトを組み合わせる
8.4コンポーズされたBicycleのサンプルソースを実際に
自分のローカル端末上で動かしたところ下記エラーが発生しました。

PartsFactory.buildの引数はconfig, parts_class = Parts
と２つ存在するためそもそも動かないのではないのではないか？
と考えており、書籍を見直したりエラーコードで検索をしておりますが、
解決できておりません

お力を貸して頂けると助かります。宜しくお願い致します。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from bicycle.rb:65:in `<main>'
bicycle.rb:32:in `build': uninitialized constant PartsFactory::Parts (NameError)
```

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :parts

  def initialize(args={})
    @size = args[:size]
    @parts = args[:parts]
  end

  def spares
    parts.spares
  end
end

require 'forwardable'
class Part
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@parts, :size, :each

  include Enumerable

  def initialize(parts)
    @parts = parts
  end

  def spares
    select { |part| part.needs_spare }
  end
end

require 'ostruct'
module PartsFactory
  def self.build(config, parts_class = Parts)
    parts_class.new(
      config.collect { |part_config|
        create_part(part_config)
      }
    )
  end

  def self.create_part(part_config)
    OpenStruct.new(
      name: part_config[0],
      description: part_config[1],
      needs_spare: part_config.fetch(2, true)
    )
  end
end

road_config = [
                ['chain', '10-speed'],
                ['tire_size', '23'],
                ['tape_color', 'red']
              ]

mountain_config = [
                    ['chain', '10-speed'],
                    ['tire_size', '2.1'],
                    ['front_shock', 'Manitou', false],
                    ['rear_sshock', 'Fox']
                  ]

road_bike = 
  Bicycle.new(
    size: 'L',
    parts: PartsFactory.build(road_config)
  )
```

バージョン情報
Rubyバージョン：ruby 2.6.5p114

Comment: `Parts` クラスが見つからないよ、というエラーですね。15行目で宣言してるクラス名が `Part` になってるので、そこを `Parts` に変えれば大丈夫だと思います

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！！！！

書籍でこのように書いておりPartsなんでないんだろうと思ってたんですが
やはり必要だったんですね...!

書籍の内容をみた限りPartクラスはこのままで良さそうで
module PartsFactoryの
def self.build(config, parts_class = Parts)がおそらく書籍上では
Partであるべきだと考えたので最終的にこちらで修正したところ動作しました!!!
アドバイスありがとうございました！！！

Comment: https://gihyo.jp/book/2016/978-4-7741-8361-9/support
にて正誤表があり書籍の間違いであることがわかりました！
サポートサイトも見なければいけませんね。。。

Answer (score 1):

pompopoさんのアドバイスで解決いたしました！

> Parts クラスが見つからないよ、というエラーですね。15行目で宣言してるクラス名が Part になってるので、そこを Parts に変えれば大丈夫だと思います – pompopo